# tkinter + figma animated GUI

Tags: python, tkinter, figma

I'm trying to redesign my application. In previous version ('old') I was using pure tkinter with python. In the new version I decided to create modern GUI. For this purpose I'm using Figma to design my UI, than I use tkinter design to convert it to python code and then I'm running it as normal app.

[image]

The main problem for now with the new GUI designed in Figma is that I don't know how to create different subpages and how to jump between them. I would like to click, for example. "DODAJ" and then I should jump into another subpage. How can I add this paging to my app generated by Figma? Maybe I should design the new UI in other language? If yes what langugage should it be?

```
# This file was generated by the Tkinter Designer by Parth Jadhav
# https://github.com/ParthJadhav/Tkinter-Designer


from pathlib import Path

# from tkinter import *
# Explicit imports to satisfy Flake8
from tkinter import Tk, Canvas, Entry, Text, Button, PhotoImage


OUTPUT_PATH = Path(__file__).parent
ASSETS_PATH = OUTPUT_PATH / Path("./assets")


def relative_to_assets(path: str) -> Path:
    return ASSETS_PATH / Path(path)


window = Tk()

window.geometry("1440x1024")
window.configure(bg = "#FFFFFF")


canvas = Canvas(
    window,
    bg = "#FFFFFF",
    height = 1024,
    width = 1440,
    bd = 0,
    highlightthickness = 0,
    relief = "ridge"
)

canvas.place(x = 0, y = 0)
canvas.create_rectangle(
    0.0,
    0.0,
    1440.0,
    1011.0,
    fill="#1D1D30",
    outline="")

canvas.create_text(
    856.0,
    402.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="Nowe gui",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("RedHatDisplay Regular", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    896.0,
    364.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="1.0.0",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("RedHatDisplay Regular", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    725.0,
    256.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="OSTATNIE ZMIANY",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("RedHatDisplay Regular", 48 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    630.0,
    79.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="XXX Application",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("RedHatDisplay Regular", 64 * -1)
)

canvas.create_rectangle(
    0.0,
    0.0,
    391.0,
    1011.0,
    fill="#282646",
    outline="")

canvas.create_text(
    94.0,
    921.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="USTAWIENIA",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("RedHatDisplay Regular", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    88.0,
    822.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="AUTO MODE",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("RedHatDisplay Regular", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    16.0,
    723.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="SPRAWD� WA�NO��",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("RedHatDisplay Regular", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    61.0,
    624.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="EDYTUJ / USU�",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("RedHatDisplay Regular", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    98.0,
    525.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="WYSZUKAJ ",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("RedHatDisplay Regular", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    132.0,
    426.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="DODAJ ",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("RedHatDisplay Regular", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_text(
    31.0,
    327.0,
    anchor="nw",
    text="WSZYSTKIE POLISY",
    fill="#FFFFFF",
    font=("RedHatDisplay Regular", 36 * -1)
)

canvas.create_rectangle(
    12.0,
    206.0,
    391.0,
    295.0,
    fill="#282746",
    outline="")

button_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("button_1.png"))
button_1 = Button(
    image=button_image_1,
    borderwidth=0,
    highlightthickness=0,
    command=lambda: print("button_1 clicked"),
    relief="flat"
)
button_1.place(
    x=18.0,
    y=212.0,
    width=373.0,
    height=76.0
)

image_image_1 = PhotoImage(
    file=relative_to_assets("image_1.png"))
image_1 = canvas.create_image(
    195.0,
    121.0,
    image=image_image_1
)
window.resizable(False, False)
window.mainloop()
```

And thats how the new input screen should look after clicking for example DODAJ. I have connected it with overlaying in Figma but it doesnt work with tkinter designer I think. Only the first screen is beeing created.
[image]

Comment: You can do is place all the widgets in a frame then pack and unpack according to your need

Comment: I think this answer to [Switch between two frames in tkinter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7546050/switch-between-two-frames-in-tkinter/7557028#7557028) would be helpful — it is an example of grouping widgets into frames and switching between them.

Answer (score 0):

create a new file for the new window or the page, n import that file using import keyword in the current file. for example:
mainscreen.py has the main screen
in this code you need to import the `dodaj.py` file using import function

```py
def dodaj():
    import dodaj
```

put this command for the dodaj button in mainscreen.py and it will work!